# Excel: filter a column by more than two values ("ends with")

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is related to another (answered) question. At:

[Excel: filter a column by more than two values](https://superuser.com/questions/623380/excel-filter-a-column-by-more-than-two-values/623471#623471)?

There is an answer for how to filter for cells equal to a set of values with more than two members. Does anyone know how this would be extended to filter for cells *ending with* one of a set of values with more than two members. Using the standard filters, I can filter for "(Ends With A) or (Ends With B)," but how would I filter for "(Ends With A) or (Ends With B) or (Ends With C)?"

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Complex criteria can always be attacked with a *"helper"* column.  Say we want to filter column **A** if the word ends with **y, j,** or **z**

In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(OR(RIGHT(A2,1)="y",RIGHT(A2,1)="j",RIGHT(A2,1)="z"),1,0)
```

and copy down..............then filter by column **B**

[image]